# How to transform realworld coordinates to image coordinates for a multi camera calibration

Tags: python, opencv, camera, calibration

I have an application with 4 cameras each directed at the same calibration board (aruco markers) with a small area of overlap between the cameras (1440 x 1080):

cam1 = bottom-right

cam2 = top-right

cam3 = bottom-left

cam4 = top-left

I succeeded in getting the camera matrices, distortion coefficients, and rotation- and translation coefficients for each camera individually.

I looked everywhere how to find the Real World XYZ coordinates for a point UV in an image of one of the cameras, but I could not find anything for a multi camera calibration?

This is the information of the 4 different cameras:

Camera matrices:

```py
[array([[53212.8927 ,     0.     ,   543.56796],
        [    0.     , 53479.6367 ,   713.23284],
        [    0.     ,     0.     ,     1.     ]]),
 array([[29981.3394 ,     0.     ,    63.59135],
        [    0.     , 30324.9596 ,  1152.35527],
        [    0.     ,     0.     ,     1.     ]]),
 array([[20926.1612 ,     0.     ,   303.31642],
        [    0.     , 21101.4537 ,   428.88867],
        [    0.     ,     0.     ,     1.     ]]),
 array([[16692.1187 ,     0.     ,   480.48346],
        [    0.     , 16780.9463 ,   458.06808],
        [    0.     ,     0.     ,     1.     ]])]
```

Ret values:

```
[0.49911996589905167,
 0.4396630965819865,
 0.4677232590789971,
 0.45881431355728325]
```

Distortion coefficients:

```py
[array([[-16.90733,  -0.92418,  -0.06731,   0.07898,  -0.0004 ]]),
 array([[ -6.77876, 149.7609 ,  -0.07488,   0.11374,  -0.19333]]),
 array([[ -3.66428, 199.94606,   0.0287 ,   0.08422,   0.63958]]),
 array([[ -1.4182 , -21.42169,   0.01521,   0.04125,   0.11401]])]
```

Translation vectors:

```
[(array([[  216.50295599],
         [ -379.24972974],
         [14808.0846043 ]]),),
 (array([[ 344.33194055],
         [-276.15482163],
         [8278.998352  ]]),),
 (array([[ 608.4655998 ],
         [-297.88196483],
         [5803.26900267]]),),
 (array([[ 554.4457446 ],
         [ -87.66756759],
         [4620.6332987 ]]),)]
```

Rotation vectors:

```
[(array([[ 0.01435556],
         [-3.17819972],
         [ 0.0689025 ]]),),
 (array([[ 0.00710524],
         [-3.06113125],
         [-0.20311682]]),),
 (array([[ 0.01955745],
         [-3.17167558],
         [-0.08129286]]),),
 (array([[ 0.00446408],
         [-3.15287827],
         [-0.06567171]]),)]
```

The board has 47 markers in X direction and 32 in Y direction

Comment: dump all the numbers you have into your question

Comment: Is this helping?

Comment: yes, insofar as the camera matrices (intrinsics, right? projection matrices?) look to be junk, and so do the translation vectors. are those four identical cameras? then the focal lengths should all be the same too, between cameras. -- I'd recommend `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` to get rid of the exponential notation. makes numbers easier to eyeball.

Comment: you'll always get useless calibrations from a **single perpendicular view** (both attributes individually cause trouble, both even more). take more pictures, with the board given some out of plane rotation, i.e. tilt. -- you'll always get bad calibration when the arucos are that tiny (in pixels). try with markers that are 2-3x larger.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But I'm still wondering how I can relate the cameras with each other. So, if I have a point for example (100, 500) in camera 1, I need to get point (1400, 500) for camera 3 (more or less)?

Comment: do you have a plane too? a point in the picture is a **ray** in the scene. if you had a ray, you could intersect it with a plane. then you'd have a point again. -- look up "epipolar lines". a point in one camera corresponds to an epipolar line in another camera. that is the basis for stereo vision.